# A question about camera coordinate transformation in 3-D space

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, eigen

I have several cameras poses of format R|t in world coordinate A, and the same camera poses R'|t' in another world coordinate B.
The question is:
**How could I get Bx if I have a new Ax coming in?**

I have tried the Kabsch algorithm implemented in Eigen, but the result is ridiculous...
Then I think that 3 pairs of `t` vectors should solve the problem because there are 7 doms in `T`. So I compute the `Tx = tAfterTrans*pinv(tBeforeTrans)`, and orthonormalize the R matrix of `Tx`. But the result is also wrong.
Do you guys have some good ideas or where I did wrong?
OpenCV and Eigen are both fine.
Thanks!

Comment: If pose A1 and B1 refer to the same place but in different origins (Ao, Bo) then you can just calculate the difference between your "know" pose to the origin of each coordinate system... something like A1.inverted *  B1.inverted.inverted = A1.inverted * B1. A1.inverted is the transformation from A1 pose to the origin of A world. Same for B1. And the difference, or transformation between 2 transformation is A * B.inverted ... thus the formula from before...

Comment: okay, thank you api55! I'll try your method!

Comment: "Pose in world coordinate A" is an ambiguous description of what the coordinates actually mean. With only that description, it is impossible to be sure any code we write is correct and it is easy to make mistakes. This article explains the issue: [Representing Robot Pose: The good, the bad, and the ugly.](http://paulfurgale.info/news/2014/6/9/representing-robot-pose-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly)